# @ error suppression operator and set_error_handler

Tags: php, logging, operator-keyword, error-reporting

I am following good programming practices and I am logging the PHP errors to file instead of displaying it to user. I use `set_error_handler()` for that.

Now the problem. For example, I have somewhere:

```
@file_exists('/some/file/that/is/outside/openbasedir.txt');
```

But despite the error suppression operator, the error message logs. I don't want that. I want suppressed errors not to pass to my error handler.

Comment: Avoid using `@`. Its a good sign, that you did something wrong and dont't want to fix it. However, the errorhandler-callback gets called, even if the statement itself is "silenced" via `@`.

Comment: I think using `@$a` is acceptable instead of `isset($a)?$a:''`. The code readability overweights the "disadvantages".

Comment: @Rok: You'll notice that it also have some performance implications; `@` hide errors, but they are still generated, formatted, error handlers are called, etc. Just structure your code so that you don't have to use isset() much.

Comment: I completely agree with KingCrunch , hiding error is really  `BAD PRACTICE` and you should stop doing it

Comment: They are not errors, they are NOTICEs.

Comment: And they are there for a reason. You should always display them in development and you can hide them in production (but in theory you should have nothing to hide), and this can be done via `error_reporting()`. The `@` operator really has no place in good code.

Comment: That you think about testing your _local variables_ with `isset()` tells me, that you _definitely_ do something wrong: Intialize your local variables!

Comment: NOTICES exist because they help to spot bugs, typos, etc. BTW you should never have to check for the existence of a variable (other than for array members).

Comment: Thanks, I know all that you wrote. @KingCrunch, what about $_POST['sth'] ? How can I initialize that?

Comment: @Rok: Read arnauds comment: "Other than for array members". And for data coming from outside its even much more important to check it!

Comment: I am eager to know, what kind of error file_exists() can throw? Don't you have it at hand, by chance?

Comment: `Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/some/path) is not within the allowed path(s):`, if you know how to avoid this warning without @ operator, please assist.

Comment: `@` can occur in a third-party code. It is used in Yii2 for instance. So you can still have it even if you don't use it. `@` being the bad practice is unrelated to the question.

Comment: PHP's error handling is sadly a huge mess. I have moved away from PHP probably 2 years ago.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This answer applies at PHP 7:

The `@` operator temporarily sets error_reporting to 0, so you can test the value of error_reporting in your error handler:

```
if (error_reporting() == 0)
    return;
```

Or even better, log only error types that are in error_reporting:

```
$error_reporting = error_reporting();
if ( !($error_reporting & $errno) )
    return;
```

---

Also take a look at the [`log_errors`](http://php.net/log_errors) and [`error_log`](http://php.net/error_log) options, for automatically logging errors to a file or to syslog.

Comment: So, basically you are saying that @ **temporarily** sets error_reporting to zero?

Comment: Didn't work for me (PHP7), but this did: if (error_reporting() == 0) { return; }

Comment: `ini_get()` didn't work for me on PHP 8, either. This did: `if ( !(error_reporting() & $errno) )`

Answer (score 9):

**Solution that also works for PHP 7**

According to the PHP docs:

> If you have set a custom error handler function with set_error_handler() then it will still get called, but this custom error handler can (and should) call error_reporting() which will return 0 when the call that triggered the error was preceded by an @.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

So you can use the following code in your error handler:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    if (error_reporting() == 0) {
        /// @ sign temporary disabled error reporting
        return;
    }

    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}

set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

Comment: A follow up question: As the @ sign temporarily sets error reporting to 0, it seems there is no way  from within the error handler to determine if the warning is triggered by code which has the @ prepended or if error reporting is disabled on the system. I would like to be able to do that, though, as I have a case where it makes sense to respect @ but not respect the general error reporting setting. Is there perhaps some workaround?

Comment: You could set a variable at the start of your code and use that variable to differentiate inside the `// @ sign temporary disabled error reporting` above. Another option is to use `ini_get('error_reporting')` to check the ini file, but that will only work if you adjusted the error reporting in configuration files.

Answer (score 5):

PHP8 behavior has changed and checking `error_reporting() == 0` in the error handler no longer works. The way to check for errors suppressed with @ in PHP8 is as follows:

```
function errorHandler($err_severity, $err_msg, $err_file, $err_line)
{
    // Skip errors suppressed by @
    if (!(error_reporting() & $err_severity)) {
        return true;
    }

    // Error handling here
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

> Warning Prior to PHP 8.0.0, the error_reporting() called inside the
> custom error handler always returned 0 if the error was suppressed by
> the @ operator. As of PHP 8.0.0, it returns the value E_ERROR |
> E_CORE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_USER_ERROR | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR |
> E_PARSE.

This means that solutions from other answers will not work :(

The @-operator became completely unusable imho.

To disable errors you will have to do the following:

```
error_reporting(0); // disable

try {
    $res = 10/0;
} catch (Throwable){
    $res = false;
}

error_reporting(-1); // enable
```

Comment: Well the error classes given with PHP 8.0.0 would have led to a fatal error stopping the script before PHP 8.0.0. Therefore suppressing them might have worked in sense of the operator suppressing the message but not the error. Its perhaps more the very specific example you give here for division by zero which turned into an error (and only was a warning beforehand) IIRC. Not sure about the _completely unusable_ part there, maybe for division by zero errors only?

Comment: This helped me find the source of a bug after upgrading to PHP 8. Thanks.

Comment: For PHP8 see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74525266/610060

Answer (score 0):

You should actually avoid usage of `@` operator. First of all, it is slow, and I would as far as to call it harmful.

What you should have instead is in `php.ini` file have two line:

```
error_repoting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
```

... or , if you do not have access to the php.ini file , then at the top of index.php (or any other bootstrap file) you should add :

```
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but just saying to avoid @ usage doesn't answer the question. PHP sometime throws exceptions, which can be caught, sometime displays stupid notices, which cannot be caught. In that case, turning off errors for the whole application is not a reasonable solution. Silencing them on the spot is not ideal either but slightly better (especially for cases like file_exists or file_get_contents which already return false in case of error, so you don't need the notice). Ideally, PHP wouldn't be broken in the way it reports errors, but since it is we need to work with that.

Comment: You should avoid usage of @ operator, but sometimes you need to use libraries which use them.

Comment: @SimonBackx there is no lack of libraries on the packagist site. You probably can find a better one. It's no 2011 anymore :D

Answer (score 0):

PHP8 code 4437 for @

```
function myErrorHandler(int $errno, string  $errstr, ?string $errfile, ?int $errline) : void {
    if (error_reporting() !== 4437)
    {
      ......
    }
}

set_error_handler("myErrorHandler", E_ALL);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).